# How to display multiple text view in single table row at run time in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, android-tablelayout

I have some table in my sqlite database. I fetched the table values and stored into array. Now I want to display multiple text view at run time dynamically. My code is http://pastie.org/5122521 . And i my logcat shows some error like this

```
  10-27 11:24:22.444: INFO/System.out(552): seek bar value---->-77
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exale.newfinace/com.exale.newfinace.Income}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
  10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:421)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1851)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:412)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at com.exale.newfinace.Income.onCreate(Income.java:402)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 10-27 13:04:15.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(868):     ... 11 more
```

Where i did mistake in code? Can anybody tell me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have create a single object of TextView and you are adding that multiple times. Might be in a loop which is creating problem. As you cannot add a single view object to the view hierarchy tree as that would destroy the tree property and create a cycle

Comment: In the loop create view object every time you add for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
do{
TableRow tr_row1 = new TableRow(this);
TextView tv=new TextView(this); // in place of this you can use your activity reference
tr_row1.add(tv);
}while(condition);
```

Comment: @malavika I have check your code you are using tr_row1 repeatedly. Just create this row inside the do while loop